# OSX 64 bit C++ DIsassembly line by line

Tags: c++, assembly, disassembly

I have been reading through the following series of articles: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/11/09/a-low-level-curriculum-for-c-and-c

The disassembled code shown and the disassembled code I am managing to produce whilst running the same code vary quite significantly and I lack the understanding to explain the differences.

Is there anyone that can step through it line by line and perhaps explain what it's doing at each step ? I get the feeling from the searching around I have done that the first few lines have something to do with frame pointers, there also seems to be a few extra lines in my disassembled code that ensures registers are empty before placing new values into them (absent from the code in the article)

I am running this on OSX (original author is using Windows) using the g++ compiler from within  XCode 4. I am really clueless as to weather or not these variances are due to the OS, the architecture (32 bit vs 64 bit maybe?) or the compiler itself. It could even be the code I guess - mine is wrapped inside the main function declaration whereas the original code makes no mention of this.

My code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 0;

    z = x + y;

}
```

My disassembled code:

```
0x100000f40:  pushq  %rbp
0x100000f41:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100000f44:  movl   $0, %eax
0x100000f49:  movl   %edi, -4(%rbp)
0x100000f4c:  movq   %rsi, -16(%rbp)
0x100000f50:  movl   $1, -20(%rbp)
0x100000f57:  movl   $2, -24(%rbp)
0x100000f5e:  movl   $0, -28(%rbp)
0x100000f65:  movl   -20(%rbp), %edi
0x100000f68:  addl   -24(%rbp), %edi
0x100000f6b:  movl   %edi, -28(%rbp)
0x100000f6e:  popq   %rbp
0x100000f6f:  ret
```

The disassembled code from the original article:

```
mov    dword ptr [ebp-8],1
mov    dword ptr [ebp-14h],2
mov    dword ptr [ebp-20h],0
mov    eax, dword ptr [ebp-8]
add    eax, dword ptr [ebp-14h]
mov    dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax
```

A full line by line breakdown would be extremely enlightening but any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major differences between your disassembled code and the article's code.

One is that the article is using the Intel assembler syntax, while your disassembled code is using the traditional Unix/AT&T assembler syntax.  Some differences between the two are documented on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax).

The other difference is that the article omits the function prologue, which sets up the stack frame, and the function epilogue, which destroys the stack frame and returns to the caller.  The program he's disassembling has to contain instructions to do those things, but his disassembler isn't showing them.  (Actually the stack frame *could* and probably would be omitted if the optimizer were enabled, but it's clearly not enabled.)

There are also some minor differences: your code is using a slightly different layout for local variables, and your code is computing the sum in a different register.

On the Mac, g++ doesn't support emitting Intel mnemonics, but clang does:

```
:; clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel t.c
:; cat t.s
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    push    RBP
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov RBP, RSP
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    mov EAX, 0
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 4], EDI
    mov QWORD PTR [RBP - 16], RSI
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 20], 1
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 24], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 28], 0
    mov EDI, DWORD PTR [RBP - 20]
    add EDI, DWORD PTR [RBP - 24]
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 28], EDI
    pop RBP
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

If you add the `-g` flag, the compiler will add debug information including source filenames and line numbers.  It's too big to put here in its entirety, but this is the relevant part:

```
    .loc    1 4 14 prologue_end     ## t.c:4:14
Ltmp5:
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 20], 1
    .loc    1 5 14                  ## t.c:5:14
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 24], 2
    .loc    1 6 14                  ## t.c:6:14
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 28], 0
    .loc    1 8 5                   ## t.c:8:5
    mov EDI, DWORD PTR [RBP - 20]
    add EDI, DWORD PTR [RBP - 24]
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 28], EDI
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the code from the original article is in your code, there's just some extra stuff around it. This:

```
0x100000f50:  movl   $1, -20(%rbp)
0x100000f57:  movl   $2, -24(%rbp)
0x100000f5e:  movl   $0, -28(%rbp)
0x100000f65:  movl   -20(%rbp), %edi
0x100000f68:  addl   -24(%rbp), %edi
0x100000f6b:  movl   %edi, -28(%rbp)
```

Corresponds directly to the 6 instructions talked about in the article.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the assembler listed as "from original article" is using "Intel" syntax, where the "disassembled output" in your post is "AT&T syntax". This explains the order of arguments to instructions being "back to front" [let's not argue about which is right or wrong, ok?], and register names are prefixed by a `%`, constants prefixed by `$`. There is also a difference in how memory locations/offsets to registers are referenced - `dword ptr [reg+offs]` in Intel assembler translates to `l` as a suffix on the instruction, and `offs(%reg)`.

The 32-bit vs. 64-bit renames some of the registers - `%rbp` is the same as `ebp` in the article code.

The actual offsets (e.g `-20`) are different partly because the registers are bigger in 64-bit, but also because you have `argc` and `argv` as part of your function arguments, which is stored as part of the start of the function - I have a feeling the original article is actually disassembling a different function than `main`.

Comment: Thanks for this - definitely cleared up a few things I didn't understand! The fact that it's a different syntax altogether explains a lot as well as your point on the differing offsets.

Comment: The original article seems fine. On x86, `argc` and `argv` would be pushed by the caller and hence be at *positive* offsets relative to `ebp` (ebp+0 is the old BP, ebp+4 is the return address, ebp+8 is the first argument...). On x86_64 OSX, the first two arguments are passed in `rdi` (`edi` in this case because it's an int) and `rsi`. It looks like it was compiled with `-O0`, so the arguments are immediately saved to the stack.

Comment: Sorry for being clueless with regards to this - but how would I enable these optimizations? Would definitely like to run it with/without and compare

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with the original article - just that it's different from `main`. Also, if this code is compiled with any level of optimisation, it will almost certainly just fold all the math into a single instruction (or no instruction, depending on whether the result is used or not).

Comment: Adding, for example `-O1` to your compile line should optimize the code - in which case, I'd expect it to produce the value 3 in a register, rather than doing the `add` operation. It will almost certainly also not use the `offs(%rbp)` type operations, but use registers. It may of course optimise everything away if `z` is not used in the code.

Comment: define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) nounwind uwtable readnone ssp {
  ret i32 0
} - This is the output with -O4

Comment: Uh, I guess that's supposed to be the optimized code, but I think it got a bit mangled, or something...